# How to access local file path in Azure power shell Run book

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Team, I am trying to upload a file from local machine to azure blob storage account. I am able to upload file by running script in local power shell. However when i tried same script in Azure Automation Power shell runbook I am getting error.

```
Test-Path -Path 'D:\UploadFolder\Sample.txt' -- Returns True in local powershell while uploading
Test-Path -Path 'D:\UploadFolder\Sample.txt' -- Returns False in azure automation powershell runbook while uploading
```

**Error:** Drive 'D' not found

I checked below code in Runbook which return false.

```
Get-PSDrive -Name 'D' -- Return false
```

**My Questions:**

1) How we can access any local file path in runbook ?

2) Do we have any blade in azure to store/create files in Automation Account itself?. (Purpose of this asking is "I Would like to create file in azure automation manually/script wise to write some content in to it and later to upload same file in Azure blob storage.)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access your local system file through Azure Automation. If you have small information like key-value, you store in Azure Automation variable section

//Get variable value in Automation PowerShell script

```
$cosmosDbAccountName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'CosmosDbAccountName'
$databaseName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'DatabaseName'
```

**Option 1**

You can upload your file in blob and read a blob from Azure Automation Script.

**Option 2**

You can use WebJob (App Service) to run PowerShell script and you can upload both script and file in WebJob.