# How to avoid the 1GB $env:TEMP) in Azure Automation Powershell

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm having a problem in a Powershell Runbook. We scan the O365 AuditLogs and write the results to disk, up to this moment we userd the $env:TEMP disk.
After the scan we upload the csv files into a storage account.
But not our csv are getting bigger than 1GB.
THis s a part of the code ..

```
    $results = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $currentStart -EndDate $currentEnd -SessionId $sessionID -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -ResultSize 5000
    if (($results | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0) {
        $outputFile = $outputPath + $recordType + "/Data_" + $currentStart.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + "_" + $currentEnd.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + "_" + $fileloopCount.ToString() + ".csv"
        Check-Dir -dirName (Split-Path -Path $outputFile)
        $results | export-csv -Path $outputFile -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Is there another way of working, I could not append and create multiple small files, upload them after creation and delete them, but I'm wondering if there would be another way.

Use Export-Csv directly to a blob-storage ?

Kr, Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow below approach to upload **1GB** file to **storage account** using powershell.

You cannot access the file located in local path from **Azure Runbook**, follow the [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115904/how-to-access-local-file-path-in-azure-power-shell-run-book) for more details by @Pankaj Rawat

I also tried to upload 1GB file from local machine to **Azure storage** using **Azure Runbook**, getting below result.

[image]

> Use Export-Csv directly to a blob-storage ?

`Export-Csv` command in **PowerShell** is used to export data to a CSV file, not directly to a blob storage in Azure.

You can use below powershell script to upload file from local to **Azure Storage account**.

```
#Authenticate to Azure
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

 Set the storage account name and container name
$storageAccountName = "emobro"
$containerName = "rithwik"
$storageAccountKey ="StoarageaccountKey"

#Get the storage account context

$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey


 Set the file path and name of the CSV file to upload
$localFilePath = "C:\Users\v-vallepuv\Downloads\samplefile.csv"
$blobName = "sample.csv"

 Upload the CSV file to Azure Blob Storage
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $storageContext -Container $containerName -File $localFilePath -Blob $blobName
```

Once ran the above powershell code, file got uploaded to **Azure storage account** successfully as below.

[image]